# UIPageViewController Conflict issue

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, uipageviewcontroller

[image]

Having trouble getting the UIPageViewController to work. the image shows the error that is occurring.

Comment: I do not see the closing brace/bracket for your viewDidLoad. Is it there?

Comment: sorry, the closing brace is there it doesn't seem to have been captured in the screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

It looks fine to me, the only things missing are the return statements of the two methods.

Since the return values are optional you can check if it compiles by just returning nil.

Sometimes I get weird behaviors with Xcode, in these cases if I'm sure the syntax is correct I just clean and recompile the project, usually it fixes the problem.